# How can I get the cells to print in my ViewController2?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to get my app to display the name of the selected cell on a different screen. I got it to display the word "Sample" but I want to show the name of the person selected. What can I do for it to show? It's just the one line of code I need to change in my prepareforSegue.

ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var ppl = [NSManagedObject]()


    @IBAction func addName(sender: AnyObject) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Client",
            message: "Add a new client",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
            style: .Default,
            handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                let textField = alert.textFields!.first
                self.saveName(textField!.text!)


                self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
            style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
            (textField: UITextField) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addAction(saveAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        presentViewController(alert,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Clients"
        accessData()
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,
            forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return ppl.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

        let person = ppl[indexPath.row]

        cell!.textLabel!.text =
            person.valueForKey("name") as? String
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("SELECTED ITEM")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("selectedView", sender: tableView)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func saveName(name: String) {

        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person",
            inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)


        person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")



        do {
            try managedContext.save()

            ppl.append(person)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    func accessData() {
        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")



        do {
            let results =
            try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            ppl = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier=="selectedView") {
            let dvc=segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
            dvc.name="Sample"



            //let selectedItem: NSManagedObject = ppl[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row] as NSManagedObject

            //dvc.name = selectedItem.valueForKey("Cell") as! String
        }
    }

}
```

ViewController2:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2:UIViewController{


    @IBOutlet weak var userDisplay: UILabel!

    var name = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        userDisplay.text = name
    }

    func printMe(){
        print("I am a controller")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily, instead of sending tableView as the sender when doing `performSegueWithIdentifier("selectedView", sender: tableView)` send the `indexPath` of the selected row, thus you have:

`performSegueWithIdentifier("selectedView", sender: indexPath)`

All you have to do then is change `prepareForSegue` method to be something like

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let indexPath = sender {
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath as! NSIndexPath)
        if let name = cell?.textLabel?.text {
            let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondVC
            dvc.name = name
        }
    }
}
```